# Repeater - fixed header and fixed foot with scrollbar in "content"

Tags: c#, html, css, repeater

I'm trying to replicate the following with a repeater:

[image]
The header is fixed and the footer is also fixed by with values returned from a data source.
What I did was take the header out of the repeater.  And added the code for the scrollbar

```
<div style="width:350px;height:200px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;">
```

Since the footer needs to be fixed I wasn't sure how to make just that row not scroll.

So I created a 2nd repeater as a fake footer. 
The problem is the cell widths do not match the first repeater b/c the scrollbar in the 1st repeater changes the total width of the row.

QUESTION: Is there a way to fix the footer so it's not scrollable?  If not, is there a better way than trial and error fixing the columns widths so it matches the 1st repeater?
thanks.

Comment: Do you have any code you can provide / a fiddle that demos what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting. There used to be more comments here and I responded to one. So I found a way around the tables not matching. not ideal...but i think does the trick. I found that you can change the colors of the scrollbar. So i just changed the scrollbar color to white and all the tables match and no scrollbar is displayed. not the best way. But it works